# MQGET big message ( > 4MB) from the queue results in error 2010

Tags: c, unix, ibm-mq, aix

I am trying to receive the message from the queue using ANSI-C and MQGET function. The problem is that I always get error 2010 (MQRC_DATA_LENGTH_ERROR).

I found out that this error concerns parameter 7 of the MQGET call (DataLength). The message on my queue has 7157460 bytes. The channel I am using for MQGET has the "Maximum message length" set to 104857600 (as well as the queue holding the message).

I am even using the MQGET from this example:
http://www.capitalware.biz/dl/code/c/msg2file.zip

And I still end up with error 2010. What am I doing wrong? Should I somehow increase the maximum size of the message in MQSERVER environment variable?

MQGET call:

```
/* ... */
MQLONG   messlen;            /* message length received       */

MQGET(Hcon,                  /* connection handle                 */
        Hobj,                /* object handle                     */
        &md,                 /* message descriptor                */
        &gmo,                /* get message options               */
        buflen,              /* pBuffer length                    */
        pBuffer,             /* pointer to message buffer         */
        &messlen,            /* message length                    */
        &CompCode,           /* completion code                   */
        &Reason);            /* reason code                       */
```

Comment: what version of MQ are you using? Documentation for 2010 says "The DataLength parameter is not valid. Either the parameter pointer is not valid, or it points to read-only storage. (It is not always possible to detect parameter pointers that are not valid; if not detected, unpredictable results occur.)

This reason can also be returned to an MQ MQI client program on the MQGET, MQPUT, or MQPUT1 call, if the BufferLength parameter exceeds the maximum message size that was negotiated for the client channel." So check if any of this is the case.

Comment: I don't know your configuration, but I am on z/OS where >4MB is an option purchased separately. So here it never works! Could that be your problem too?

Comment: I am using Websphere MQ 7.5 on Unix. The MQGET program is on another unix (AIX). I've read the docs about this problem but these aren't valid for me. Try reading the source from the msg2file i gave in the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got it! The answer is to use MQCONNX call to connect to queue manager.

Example:

```
#include <cmqxc.h>
/* ... */
MQCNO   mqcno = {MQCNO_DEFAULT} ; /* Connection options */
MQCD    mqcd  = {MQCD_CLIENT_CONN_DEFAULT};  /* Channel Defs */

/* ... */
mqcd.MaxMsgLength = 104857600L; /* 100 MB */

MQCONNX(mQueueManager.Name,
     &mqcno,
     &mQueueManager.ConnectionHandle,
     &mQueueManager.CompletionCode,
     &mQueueManager.ReasonCode);
```

It worked like a charm!

But please remember - if you find yourself needing to increase the maximum message size - think twice. There is probably something wrong with the design. In another words - MQ should not be used for transferring big messages. MQ File Transfer Edition is one of the solutions then.

Comment: Glad you worked it out!  I've made a minor correction to your post.  As of v7.5 FTE packaging changed from a stand-alone product to delivered integrated with WMQ and sold as an entitlement. There is still a separate part number and license fee and instead of a separate download and install, you simply turn on the capability.

Comment: That is what I meant. I guess I've oversimplified the sentence. Thanks anyway!